# How to insert/remove some elements of same value in a multiset?

Tags: c++, multiset

Suppose I have a multiset of integers and I want to insert 3, n times into the multiset. I can obviously do it using a for loop but is there any other way to do it using some function in the stl?

Comment: maybe you can use an unordered_map/map to store the number of element in a set?

Comment: `s.insert({3, 3, 3, 3});`

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
// Assuming n is not known at compile time
int* array = new int[n];

// Set all elements of array to value 3
std::fill_n(array, n, 3);

// Create multiset using array to initialize it
std::multiset<int> myMultiSet(array, array + n);

// Free memory
delete[] array;
```

Comment: I would suggest using vector instead of array